# Markov chain constant transition matrix

Tags: probability, markov-chains, transition-matrix

I am struggling with part B of this problem. I understand Markov chains and transition matrices but I'm stuck on where to start. Maybe it is just the wording of the problem. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

[image]

I have figured out that the transition matrix is

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
0.95  &  0.06  &   0 \\
0.04  &  0.9   &  0.1 \\
0.01  &  0.04  &  0.9 
\end{bmatrix} $$

Comment: Do you know what the stationary distribution of a Markov chain is?

Comment: Try to find a vector $\mathbf v$ such that $\mathbf v P=\mathbf v$ where $P$ is your transition matrix. The problem and wording is definitely weird, as a bird population will grow and decline with reproduction and mortality. So I guess we are to assume that the birds all have eternal life and never reproduce, i.e. that the total population size is constant. Or maybe just assume that the net growth rate for each region is identical might be enough.

Answer (score 2):

Let $ x $ be the vector with the fraction of population in each country (ordered consistent with how you ordered the entries in the matrix).

Then the question asks "Is there a vector x (distribution of the population) so that $ A x = x $ (where $ A $ is the transition matrix)?"  (Is there a vector such that if everyone migrates, you again end up with exactly the same distribution of the matrix?)

Hmmm, if you look carefully at this, you will recognize this as an eigenvalue problem $ A x = \lambda x $ except that $ \lambda = 1 $...  What does this mean?  I'll let you ponder this, and maybe will give another hint later.

Comment: I have created an augmented matrix $A-1I$. My next step would be use the formula to find the characteristic polynomial of a 3x3 matrix. Is this on the right path?

Comment: You do not need to solve the characteristic polynomial (whose roots are the eigenvalues) because you already know that 1 is an eigenvalue of $A$ since $A$ is a stochastic matrix. You don't care about the other eigenvalues - you only wish to an eigenvector for $\lambda = 1$

Comment: Ah. I'm following now. Let me solve for the eigenvector of eigenvalue 1. Hold on.

Comment: I found the eigen vector `x3[2.30769, -25/13, 1]`. So would `[2.30769, -25/13, 1]` be my vector $x$?

Comment: You should not have a mixture of positive and negative entries. There must be a mistake. Try again. Then multiply by a constant so that the entries are nonnegative and add to 1.